# how to attach nightwatchjs to nodejs Desktop App

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

Our team uses Nightwatchjs and I need to use it to test a Desktop Nodejs App. I can't find any information on how to do this. I am new to nightwatch, but I have gone thru tutorials and am able to use it to test a web app.

Can someone share the configuration setup for Nightwatch to connect to a Desktop App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NightwatchJS is not capable of testing desktop application, as you can see on their official site it is only for browser based apps and websites.